# Rails logic not firing on `false` results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Receiving as an API an array of hashes

```
@request['clients'].each do |client|
```

validations are being executed on each `client`attributes.  However, rails logic is failing to fire up on false statements and this ignoring them.  Example validation:

```
  def client_type_ok
    if @this_client['type'] == "ADT" || @this_client['type'] == "CHD"
      true
    else
      false
      @error_code_39 = true
    end
  end
```

The controller action wants to execute only when true conditions are met:

```
if client_type_ok && client_type_ok
```

However Rails.logger is clearly confirming that this condition is being passed through although `false`.

```
Rails.logger.info !@this_client['type'].blank?
Rails.logger.info  @this_client['type']
Rails.logger.info "not"
Rails.logger.info  @this_client['type'] != "ADT"
Rails.logger.info "ADT"
Rails.logger.info @this_client['type'] == "ADT"
```

is returning

```
true
APT
not
true
ADT
` `
```

The bottom is generated as a blank.  The same occurs replacing Rails.logger with `p`.  All logic of this action is ignoring false results.  While I can attempt to devise processing cases of fully true cases, this is inconvenient and counter-intuitive.

Thus, there appears to be a meta function which is impeding the handling of false cases.  How can this be tracked down?  Can Rails.logger logic be step traced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not returning false there

```
  def client_type_ok
    if @this_client['type'] == "ADT" || @this_client['type'] == "CHD"
      true
    else
      false # this is not doing anything. Simply ignored.
      @error_code_39 = true # result of this assignment will be true.
                            # and it also is the last expression of the if
                            # so it becomes the implicit return value of the method
    end
  end
```

Comment: if the value being handled is `APT`, should this not be returning false?

Comment: @Jerome: No. Have you seen my comments?

Comment: oh so `error_code`is also proxing as the state of `client_type_ok`.  In other words, to be effective, they need to be inverted.  I assumed because a statement was there, it would be interpreted as an entity on its own; silly me.

Comment: @Jerome: yep, have their places swapped.

Answer (score 1):

```
  def client_type_ok
    if @this_client['type'] == "ADT" || @this_client['type'] == "CHD"
      true
    else
      false
      @error_code_39 = true
    end
  end
```

As Sergio mentiond in the above answer,The return value of yur method will be true for the else condtion. You need to swap the places or You can rewrite the above method

```
def client_type_ok
    return true if %w(ADT CHD).include?(@this_client['type'])

    @error_code_39 = true
    false
  end
```